# SSL cert not verifying, AWS interfering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

Previous Setup: AWS load balancer and AWS cert. 
current setup: GeoTrust QuickSSL cert from host provider, on apache

My host provider has given me the C NAME details and I added them in route53, but the https doesn’t seem to want to resolve. http://www.example.com works great, but  https://www.example.com shows nothing. I have deleted the amazon cert, but is AWS still having an effect? There are 2 other cname records in AWS that I haven’t changed or removed.

I have posted screenshots of the dns records. I changed the A records already so the site points to the correct IP. the nameservers are unchanged - still AWS.

It was previously setup with a weird certificate (previous person) that just referred to (literally) example.com - this cert went out of date. So I setup a new one in amazon. The AWS cert didn’t work at first until I linked it to route53, which iirc linked to a load balancer. I have also deleted the lb.

I just realised something. The cert I setup (since deleted) in AWS was in region Ireland (where the business is based), but if I change the region to n. Carolina, there is an AWS cert active there:

Domain name:
*.example.com

Record Name:
_09ede9a0bba2bcf36e9f0c4f843f1397.example.com.

Record Type:
CNAME

Record Value:
_specificaws.number.acm-validations.aws.

Should I just delete this too? Is it enough to remove the cname record, or do I delete the cert?

Edit: more details and screenshots removed 
Edit2: removed reference to actual domain

Comment: You just need to set SSL / TLS up correctly on your web server. You really need to give us much more information about your environment and configuration - is this EC2, what web server you're using, web server configuration, firewall configuration, etc. Please edit your question to give that information.

Comment: If you're going to post screenshots, please make them right way up, so people can see them. The main thing we need to help is a description of your environment and your web server configuration. For example, you may be using a load balancer and AWS certificate manager, you may be using Apache and Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your **www.example.com** doesn't listen on port 443 (HTTPS) hence we're unable to check your certificates.

   ```
   $ telnet www.example.com 443
   Trying 192.0.0123...
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
   ```
2. That `_09ed...1397.example.com.` DNS record is just for *AWS Certificate Manager* (ACM) domain validation purposes, it's not the actual certificate.
3. Guessing from the IP you are no longer hosting the site on AWS so you can't use ACM certificates. You'll have to obtain one e.g. through [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Hi MLu, many thanks for your answer.  would you mind removing references to the website and the IP numbers etc? The solution for me was that the A records needed to be updated with the new IP address, which I hadn't received from the host. Also the .htaccess file needed code to allow https.

Comment: @PaulMurphy Ok, done. If it helped please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks.